# Does any numerical diff.eq. solver give correct results given small step-size?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I've seen that there are less stable numerical differential equation solving methods, like using plain Euler steps $y(x+h)=y(x)+hf(x)$. For a given $h$ there are better methods.

But when solving differential equation problems, does just *any* method - no matter how basic - still give a correct result (e.g. for some range $[x_0,x_1]$) if you chose *sufficiently small* $h$?

I assume that you plug in forward or backward differences for differentials. For example, if errors would add up after a given number of steps, then decreasing $h$ wouldn't help and you'd rather search for a better method.

Comment: Step size is usually a tradeoff between roundoff error $\epsilon_1 \sim O(h^{-1})$ and truncation error, which is $\varepsilon_2 \sim O(h^p)$ with $p$ being the order of the method. Each method has its optimal step (that minimizes $\epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2$) and usually a method with bigger order $p$ achieves a better result at the optimal $h$.

Comment: @uranix While that is a practical concern, I think in the context of this question you can assume arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Comment: @lan then the answer will be "yes" provided the method is stable

Comment: As a remark: for finite difference schemes, the Lax equivalence theorem tells us that the discretization must be stable and consistent in order to be convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are conditions which must be met. The condition you speak of is sometimes called O-stability or zero-stability (truly, the books on my shelf refer to this concept both ways, which I chalk up as a divergence in typography somewhere down the line).

A solver is guaranteed to converge only if the differential equation is zero-stable. Zero-stability is equivalent to a Lipschitz criterion on the method:

> A method is zero-stable if there exist constants $h_0$ and $K$ such that given approximate solutions denote $x^h$, $z^h$, that whenever $h \le h_0$, $\|x^h - z^h\| \le K\left[|x_0-z_0| + \|\Delta_h x^h - \Delta_h z^h\|\right]$, where $\Delta_h$ represents a finite-difference operator.

In other words, zero-stability says that refinements of the mesh don't introduce singularities into the solution. Not all systems are zero-stable for all methods.

Comment: What's the difference between zero stability and in just stability? The derivative term?

Comment: @uranix There are many different types of stability that are discussed when talking about ordinary differential equations. Generally speaking, "stability" of a dynamical system refers to its tendency to not blow up over time. When discussing numerical methods, "stability" is too broad a term; we might say that a method is stable if it converges, but this is usually unsatisfying. Instead, we talk about zero-stability, or absolute-stability, or A-stability. We can also talk of stiff problems, where the conditions for stability are far stricter than the accuracy estimates.

Comment: We can still use non A-stable method for a stiff problem, that just would require rather small step.

Comment: Yes, but convergence is not guaranteed.

Comment: If the problem is well-posessed it does.

Comment: Untrue; if you'd like to present a counterexample to the convergence theorem, by all means please do, but the Lipschitz requirement is well-established. Unless by well-positioned you mean that it satisfies these conditions, but those are just words without substance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24112/discussion-between-uranix-and-arkamis).

Comment: I cannot, I am on mobile.

Comment: What is definition of "convergence" here? (I'm new to this) I imagine naively running an Euler step from a starting point $x_0$ and seeing the the correct function will be reproduced on an fixed interval $[x_0, x_1]$ . Is this the same? Shouldn't any finite step solution be correct at least a few steps, given small $h$?

Comment: @gerenuk there is a formal definition of convergence. I will post it when I'm off mobile.

Comment: @Gerenuk Convergence is defined as
$${}{}$$
A method is convergent if applying the method to any ODE in the form $y' = f(t,y)$ that is Lipschitz in $y$, using starting values that converge in the limit sense to the correct initial values*, we have that for every fixed time $T > 0$, the following holds:
$$\lim_{\substack{h \to 0 \\ Nh = T}} Y^N = y(T).$$
Note, $Y^m$ denotes the numerical approximation to $y$ at the $m$-th step.
$${}{}$$
*This condition is necessary for multi-step methods.